# An example of a morphism which does not preserve normality.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

While doing an exercise, I was prompted to tell what I could say about the image of a normal subgroup under a morphism. While trying to reach a conclusion, I was able to demonstrate that if it is surjective, then it preserves normality. But I could not do it if it was not surjective. So, is there an example of a morphism which does not preserve normality, or did I miss something?

Comment: How about inclusion of any subgroup which is not normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C_2 = \langle a | a^2\rangle$, be the cyclic group with two elements. Let $G = \langle a, b | a^2 \rangle$. Then there exists the obvious inclusion $C_2 \hookrightarrow G$. Note hat $C_2$ is a normal subgroup of itself, but its image is certainly not normal in $G$. (For example, $bC_2b^{-1} \neq C_2$.)